# Having trouble understanding function involving number addition

Tags: javascript

```
function NumberAddition(str) { 
  var nstr = str.match(/[0-9]+/g);
  var total = 0;
     if (nstr !== null) 
   for (var i = 0; i < nstr.length; i++) {
    total += nstr[i]*1;
  }    
  // code goes here  
  return total; 
  }
```

I was looking at answers in coderbyte.com and this was one of them. My question is about the `total += nstr[i]*1` section. if I remove the `*1` the answer is concatenated to "2344". However the answer should be 23+4+4=31. why is this?

Answer (score 3):

The `*1` forces the string in `nstr[i]` to be converted to a number. Another way to do that would be

```
  total += +nstr[i];
```

The `*` (multiplication) operator is only meaningful for numbers, and the language definition stipulates that when its arguments are *not* numbers, they should be converted. Of course, if `nstr[i]` isn't really a number (unlikely in your case, if not impossible) then the result would be a `NaN` value. Similarly, the unary `+` operator also forces its operand to be converted to a number.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying a value by 1 is a way to ensure that it gets converted to a number if it isn't.  When you add two things in JavaScript, if *either* is a string then the operation gets evaluated as string concatenation, not addition.  Since the values in `nstr` were the result of a regular expression match, they are string values, not number values.

You can multiply a value by 1 to make sure that it is treated as a number.  The canonical JavaScript way to do this is to use the unary `+` operator (`total += +(nstr[i]);`).

```
> "1"+1
"11"
> 1+"1"
"11"
> 1+1
2
> ("1"*1)+1
2
> (+"1")+1
2
```

Comment: @Connor–note that "conversion" to number is only for the sake of evaluating the expression, `nstr[i]` remains a string.